# Methods to operate over all columns in 2D numpy array.

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of lists of values (where each list of values is the same length), in a 2D ndarray. 
Example

```
[[0,1,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,0,1]]
```

I would like to perform an operation which averages the column and returns if the the average is greater than .5. How would I achieve this in numpy?

I know I could use

```
for i in range(len(vectors[0])):
    cur_vals = []        
    for j in range(len(vectors)):
        cur_vals.append(vectors[j][i])
    col_operation(cur_vals)
```

However I have been told that numpy provides utilities similar to R to do this so I am looking specifically for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an axis argument to `.mean()`:

```
In [180]: a
Out[180]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])

In [194]: a.mean(axis=0)
Out[194]: array([ 0.4,  0.6,  0.4])
```

Now generate a boolean mask like this:

```
In [195]: a.mean(axis=0) > .5
Out[195]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

To get the column with mean > .5, use boolean indexing:

```
In [196]: a.T[a.mean(axis=0) > .5] # you'll need the transpose first
Out[196]: array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I understand the axis concept much better. However I worded my question wrong I meant the columns as in the i th element of each sub array. For the example array I gave I would like to get np.mean(vectors, axis =?) = [2/5,3/5,2/5] > .5 -> [False, True, False]. Would I set axis = 2 for this?

Comment: @JamesSteel Close. axis=0. And it would still work. :) Let me edit.